# How do I keep my AIOSQLite database open for my Discord Python bot?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

How do I keep my database that I created with the AIOSQLite library open for my DiscordPY bot so that I don't have to keep on creating new connections and closing them on every command and event that I create?

Comment: Commands and events come in quite slowly, right?  We're talking a few command per minute, not 10 per second.  Creating new connections shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Comment: Unless the bot is in a high traffic guild(s), some bots use 2-3 commands at the same time,  why don't you keep a long-term connection pool to the database?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński what;s a "connection pool" and how do I make one?

Comment: [Connection pools](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), I’m unsure how would you make one, I haven’t used aiosqlite but I’m sure if you take a look at the docs you’re gonna find something like that, though if you’re using sqlite as your database that means that the bot is small, a long term single connection will also do the trick.

Comment: Upon further research I found out that aiosqlite doesn’t support connection pools (I suppose it’s because sqlite is a small database meant for small projects), as I said before a single long-term connection will also work.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Oh, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, I have found out that creating an asynchronous thread which keeps on making the database connection global can keep the database always open. I have also found out that closing the database is not necessary, but can be done as the asynchronous thread will keep on opening it and so will open it afterwards.

```
class EternalAsynchronousDatabase(Thread):
    """
    The asynchronous thread.
    """
    def run(self):
        loop = new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self._run())
        loop.close()
    async def _run(self):
        global db
        db = await connect(discord_bot.name.lower().replace(' ', '_') + '.db')

asyncdb = EternalAsynchronousDatabase()
asyncdb.start()

try:
    asyncdb.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

And then, it can always be awaited like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def register(ctx):
    await db.executescript(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (current_username TEXT, discriminator INTEGER, id INTEGER);'
        'INSERT INTO users VALUES ("?", ?, ?)', (ctx.author.name, ctx.author.discriminator, ctx.author.id)
    )
```